# Working with a view without a particular model in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a view with one DropDown list and a text box. These two (attributes) are not belonging to a particular model.

Then How can I set the MaxLength property of the Text Box and how can I set the Mandatory validation.?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can use CSS to do it.

Comment: Hi Thank you for quick reply.
How to use CSS for Mandatory. ?

Comment: You use Css to maxlenght, and Jquery to mandatory ( required )

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS to set the maxlenght

```
 new { @maxlength="4" }
```

and use Jquery to do a Valitation

http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/

Comment: For me Maxlength is working, but for Jquery ,
I implemented as below. it is not working to me. Anything wrong with me..
  <label>Track Code: (required) <span class="mandate" >*</span></label>
                <input name="txtTrackCode", maxlength="4"   id="trackcodeid" type="text"  required  />

Comment: and you add the action to a button to validate? read the http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/ have a full sample there.